# What happened to the Azor Ahai prophecy after S08E03?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I dont really understand the idea of the prophecy anymore.

> Arya killed the Night King

so what was the point of the prophecy? I thought Jon or Dany were the Prince That Was Promised. Can anyone explain?

Comment: lolololololololololol

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine. Maybe in the showverse, Azor-Ahai is a mythical hero who will come along to slay the biggest threat the mankind has ever seen......Cersei Lannister and Bronn.

Comment: Vanished as quickly as the dothrakis

Comment: I think after Melisandre was forced to accept that she might have gone a step or two too far with Stanis, she wrote the Azor Ahai idea off as a bad idea

Comment: But that's been a long time prophecy, known for 1000s of years, it might have changed during generations but not this drastically

Comment: There is one other possibility I think people are ignoring: the "prophecy" might have just been Nostradamus-level nonsense.

Comment: Azor Ahai and The Prince That Was Promised might not even refer to the same prophecy or person.

Comment: “I thought Jon or Dany were the Prince That Was Promised. Can anyone explain?” Yes! They weren't. You're welcome.

Comment: Beric Dondarion was the dude with the fiery sword but sacrificed himself to protect Arya.  He may have been her Lightbringer in the sense of sacrifice but not a true weapon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's stopping Arya from being the Azor Ahai. She became Azor Ahai because she acted on the prophecy and made it true.

I can't talk about the Azor Ahai prophecy from the books as I haven't read them.

In the show, however, the prophecy, as told by Melisandre, goes like this

> The Long Night is coming. Only the prince *[prince or princess, according to Missandei’s translation]* that was promised can bring the dawn … I believe you have a role to play, as does another. Summon Jon Snow.

She also claims that prophecies are dangerous things and she has been wrong in interpreting them.

She first claims Stannis to be the Azor Ahai but upon his death, when she returns to Castle Black & resurrects Jon Snow, she says to Davos that Jon is the Prince that was promised. But when Jon banishes her she goes to Daenerys & tells the prophecy to her.

In the show, at this point, Melisandre doesn't claims that Daenerys or Jon Snow is the "Prince That Was Promised". She only claims they have a role to play.

Back in season 3, Melisandre prophecises to Arya that she sees darkness in her & in that darkness eyes staring back at her. Brown, green & blue eyes she will shut forever and repeats it today because she can now correctly interprete the visions she saw in the flames.

Prophecises are that only, people who believe in them, act accordingly & in turn make it true.

It's the similar case in Harry Potter, Voldemort acted on a prophecy & made Harry Potter the chosen one. If he didn't act on it & try to kill Harry as child, that prophecy would be bullshit & he would still be alive & more powerful.

Edit:- [Here is an excellent review of the episode by Laura Hudson for The Wired about The Problem With Prophecies](https://www.wired.com/story/game-of-thrones-recap-s8-e3/?utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter&utm_social-type=owned&mbid=social_twitter&utm_campaign=wired&utm_brand=wired)

> Like so many fundamentalists, she(Melisandre) saw a cataclysmic threat
>   solely through the lens of her scripture, insisting it was being
>   fulfilled chapter and verse, pointing to all the prophetic "evidence"
>   with the myopic, connect-the-dots-sheeple fervor of a conspiracy
>   theorist.
>
> But prophecies and magic are a slippery business in Game of Thrones,
>   both real and fallible, true and apocryphal. In that sense they are
>   stories, and all stories are true in one sense or another—but what
>   they tell us about our future depends not on what they say so much as
>   what we decide that they mean.
>
> **Stannis was not Azor Ahai, after all, and the show remains agnostic on
>   whether Arya's shanking of the Night King makes her the Princess Who
>   Was Promised or just a kick-ass girl with a cool dagger at the right
>   time. Sure, we can go back through the legend and find ways to connect
>   Arya to passages about smoke and salt and blood—and sure, Valyrian
>   steel was forged by dragonfire according to some accounts, so in that
>   sense she was wielding a fiery blade. But if we can squint and make
>   enough of the piece fit, does that mean a prophecy has been fulfilled
>   or just that we've skillfully reimagined the outcome to line up with
>   the story we expected to hear?**
>
> That's the thing about stories, the ones we tell both about ourselves
>   and the world we live in; they're only useful insofar as they get us
>   where we need to go, when they serve us and not the other way around.

Comment: Good catch. Although I think the book might differ from what the show showed us, we only have to be based in previous seasons for the Azor Ahai prophecy and not in written material.

Comment: Yeah, good explanation, I guess I was thinking of a combination of the book/tv show prophecy, thus maybe in the TV show it could be respected. In the book I think there were a number of signs that described the birth(a red comet I think was one of them). And also the whole Lyana+Rhaegar how I understood it was part of the prophecy, thus it didnt really make sense. I hope they explain this better in the next episodes, since it was a bit of a letdown. I loved the episode but I guess the clues were pointing somewhere else for how some stuff was supposed to happen.

Comment: didn't the show mention that the one who was promised should be born admist salt and smoke? and that he would be born from the line of Prince Prince Aerys and Princess Rhaella?

Comment: @Kepotx Yeah, that's what I meant. It was really cool it not being predictable, but at the same time it felt like it didn't really respect all the hints that were given before this episode. They just chose Arya more for the wasn't expecting that factor.

Comment: @Kepotx it also mentioned something about the bleeding star which was to mean Ser Arthur Dayne's sword which was made from a star & when Ned picked it up & stabbed him, it became a bleeding star & he places it near lyanna's bed. So Jon should be AA

Comment: @KharoBangdo Daenerys was also born admist salt (dragonstone during a strong storm), reborn admist smoke, wake dragons from stone, and the next day, a red commet appear, so bleeding star is also checked.

Comment: @Kepotx wait, so Stannis didn't fulfill any part of prophecy & was still chosen as AA by Mel? I think she was relying on connecting the written prophecy & her visions & trying to make sense of it as she went along, as I said in the answer

Comment: @KharoBangdo I think you are probably right, but it is a bit of a stretch, it felt like the last Jedi with Snoke, so much build up and then he died, no backstory, no explanation, didn't really make sense build up wise, Bran didn't do anything in the episode, he just sat there, felt like this was the conclusion of his journey, but he didn't contribute at all to it, as well as Jons. He doesn't want to participate in the Game of Thrones.. and Cersei now is the ultimate tier level boss? Feels a bit anti-climactic after facing the literal army of the dead.

Comment: @Starseeker Bran had to be doing more than that. Maybe we get it next episode. People are theorizing that Bran is Lord of Light & he warged in the past to set up chess pieces for the final act to take place. Let's see

Comment: @KharoBangdo "Azor Ahai will be reborn amidst smoke and salt wielding the flaming sword Lightbringer" Dragonstone is a good combination of salt and smoke, being a volcanic island. Also, Stanis wield a magic sword, and even if not the descendent of Aerys and Rhaella, he have targaryen blood. While Jon and Dany seems to fit better to the description, Stannis still check some marks